# Karma Expected a spy, but got Function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, spy

**EDIT:** I am not sure what was wrong, but I kept writing tests and when I hit 80 tests the error stopped appearing.

I have my angular project setup to run unit tests using Karma and Jasmine. I have been adding tests recently and now whenever I get to 70 or more tests running I get this message after all of the tests have run:

```
ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', '<toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', Error{}, 'Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)
at compare (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d:3340:17)
at Expectation.toHaveBeenCalledWith (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d:1543:35)
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/cmaxfield/workspace/carbon-angular/src/app/select/select.component.spec.ts:73:36
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/cmaxfield/workspace/carbon-angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/cmaxfield/workspace/carbon-angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128:1)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/cmaxfield/workspace/carbon-angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/cmaxfield/workspace/carbon-angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:1)
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/cmaxfield/workspace/carbon-angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:872:1
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/cmaxfield/workspace/carbon-angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:1)
at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/cmaxfield/workspace/carbon-angular/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:159:1)'
```

All of my tests execute successfully and karma finishes without any issues even though this error appears:

```
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 70 of 70 SUCCESS (3.541 secs / 3.246 secs)
TOTAL: 70 SUCCESS
```

If I comment out even one test (it doesn't matter which one) then that error message no longer appears and I haven't been able to figure out what is going on.

This is my `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
basePath: '',
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-junit-reporter'),
  require('karma-spec-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage'),
  require('karma-remap-coverage'),
  require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
],
client: {
  clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
},
angularCli: {
  environment: 'dev',
},
reporters: ['junit', 'spec'],
junitReporter: {
  outputDir: 'out', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
  outputFile: undefined, // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
  suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
  useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
  nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
  classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
  properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
  xmlVersion: null, // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
},
specReporter: {
  maxLogLines: 5, // limit number of lines logged per test
  suppressErrorSummary: true, // do not print error summary
  suppressFailed: false, // do not print information about failed tests
  suppressPassed: false, // do not print information about passed tests
  suppressSkipped: false, // do not print information about skipped tests
  showSpecTiming: false, // print the time elapsed for each spec
},
coverageReporter: {
  type: 'in-memory',
},

remapCoverageReporter: {
  'text-summary': null,
  json: './coverage/coverage.json',
  cobertura: './coverage/cobertura.xml',
  html: './coverage/html',
},
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
singleRun: false,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved itself after continuing to add tests and reach 80 tests, not sure why there was a problem with this random number of tests.